# Local linear operator in physical and Fourier space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

A friend of mine raise an interesting question.

Let $V$ be a dense subset in $L^2(\Bbb R)$. The choice of $V$ is completely  under our control, we can even take $V=\cal D(\Bbb R)$ or $V=\cal S(\Bbb R)$.

Let also $T$ be a linear operator defined on $V$ such that it acts locally on both the physical space on the Fourier space.

I wonder if we can prove that $$T = \sum_{k=1}^{n}p_k(x)\partial_x^k$$ where $p_k(x)$ is a polynomial. If we can, was it shown already? If we can not, what are the counterexamples or the reasoning behind this negative result?

I'll be glad to hear all suggestions.

Comment: I think it's going to be relevant that “If the support of a generalized function $f$ is the point $\{0\}$, then in a unique manner it appears in the form $f(x) = \sum_{|α|=0}^m C_α D^α \delta(x).$” (Vladimirov's Equations of Mathematical Physics, p. 117 in the New York 1971 edition). But somehow I can't proceed much farther from there without making a lot of additional assumptions.